# How can I forward a port from the IP of an network interface to the same IP with iptables?

Tags: iptables, ip, port, port-forwarding

I need to forward a port in an IP of an interface to the same IP but with a different target port.

First I add a bridge and add an IP to it:

```
ip link add br0 type bridge
ip link set br0 up
ip address add 10.0.0.1/32 dev br0
```

And I tried with iptables with DNAT:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i br0 -p tcp -d 10.0.0.1 --dport 1111 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.1:9050
```

The port is not forwarded:

```
$ torsocks -a 10.0.0.1 -P 1111 w3m duckduckgo.com
w3m: Can't load duckduckgo.com.
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered how:

iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p tcp -o lo -d 10.0.0.1 --dport 1111 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.1:9050

iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -d 10.0.0.1 -p tcp --dport 1111 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.1:9050